# Not able to persist H2 DB in the Spring boot app

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I am trying to persist the H2 db in my local in my spring boot app.

Following is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/Users/Saurav/Documents/Data/urldata  
spring.datasource.username=sa  
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

In my `/Users/Saurav/Documents/Data` i see 2 files `urldata.mv.db` and `urldata.trace.db` getting created but nothing in the `/Users/Saurav/Documents/Data/urldata` folder.

I am not able to login to H2-Console as well. It says invalid username and password.

It seems still the in memory version of H2 is being used since inserting and fetching of data within the server session works.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: if you want  your DB to be created in the `urldata` folder then you should declare: `/Users/Saurav/Documents/Data/urldata/urldata`. The last part of url is the DB name for H2, not the folder. Also how do you access the console?

Comment: @Sergei ...thanks for the reply ...i am accessing the console through localhost web http://localhost:8080/h2-console...